# Installing dpkg-dev on Xenial

Tags: apt, dpkg

Toying with Ubuntu xenial for php, but I need to grab the php source for a specific extension. Trying to do, I get:

```
$ sudo apt-get source php7.0

> dpkg-source: not found
```

Googling reveals that this *should* be included with `dpkg-dev`, which seems to be listed for ubuntu 16.x, yet I get the error:

```
$ sudo apt-get install dpkg-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package dpkg-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'dpkg-dev' has no installation candidate
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing. Is there something else that provides dpkg-source now?

Edit: output of `sudo apt update`

```
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
```

Here's my sources.list:

`deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main`

Comment: Add the output of `sudo apt update` please.

Comment: Added the output

Answer (score 0):

Solved, by adding the following to my `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

`deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main`